# How can I get a substring of an ID name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of buttons within a section, each with an id of the form `#balls-left-n`, where n ranges from 1 to 15.

When one of these buttons is clicked, I want to grab the number from the id that was clicked and hide all of the buttons with ids that have names including numbers that are greater than the one clicked on.

So, if `#balls-left-13` is clicked, I want to hide `#balls-left-14` and `#balls-left-15`. But if `#balls-left-3` is clicked I want to hide all the buttons from `#balls-left-4` through `#balls-left-15`.

I'm a novice at web-dev so if I've made other mistakes or taken a poor approach don't hesitate to point that out.

I have a handler for each of the buttons (which if I knew more could probably be one function) that look like this:

```
$("#balls-left-14").click(function() {
    var num_balls = $(this).attr('id').match(/[\d]/);
    j_end_balls_on_table = 14;
    $("#balls-left button:gt(num_balls-2)").hide;
    ...
    other stuff
    ...
});
```

This didn't work and I get an error that `num_balls` is `undefined`, which I don't understand.
`#balls-left` is the section all of the buttons are inside of.

relevant HTML as requested

```
<section id="balls-left">
    <h2>How Many Balls are Left on the Table?</h2>          
    <button type="button" id="balls-left-2" class="x-balls-left">2</button>
    <button type="button" id="balls-left-3" class="x-balls-left">3</button>
    <button type="button" id="balls-left-4" class="x-balls-left">4</button>
    <button type="button" id="balls-left-5" class="x-balls-left">5</button>
    <button type="button" id="balls-left-6" class="x-balls-left">6</button>
    <button type="button" id="balls-left-7" class="x-balls-left">7</button>
    <button type="button" id="balls-left-8" class="x-balls-left">8</button>
    <button type="button" id="balls-left-9" class="x-balls-left">9</button>
    <button type="button" id="balls-left-10" class="x-balls-left">10</button>
    <button type="button" id="balls-left-11" class="x-balls-left">11</button>
    <button type="button" id="balls-left-12" class="x-balls-left">12</button>
    <button type="button" id="balls-left-13" class="x-balls-left">13</button>
    <button type="button" id="balls-left-14" class="x-balls-left">14</button>
    <button type="button" id="balls-left-15" class="x-balls-left">15</button>
</section>
```

Comment: I didn't see how to mark things as code. How do I do that?

Comment: It sounds like you're storing data within an ID. This is a poor choice for managing data, and would generally be better served by using a `[data-*]` attribute, and the `.data()` method.

Comment: Instead of encoding useful data in your `id`, how about `data-balls="14"`?

Comment: Could you plz post your html as well.

Comment: So, you're suggesting I have all my buttons with a class in common, and then use data-* to distinguish them?  Can I use a handler to sese one button from another this way?

Comment: use a common class for your click handler as well, rather than defining one for each

Comment: @JohnBiddle I would suggest doing what you're doing but add a `data` attribute. `<button type="button" id="balls-left-14" class="x-balls-left" data-num="14">14</button>`. That way, later on when you need the number, you can just use `$(this).data('num');`.

Comment: You might don't even need all of these if your elements to hide share the same parent. Just set class on click `.selected` and hide the rest using CSS `.selected.x-balls-left ~ .x-balls-left {display: none;}`

Comment: @JohnBiddle I've updated my answer. Kindly check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might don't even need all of these if your elements to hide share the same parent. Just set class on click .selected and hide the rest using CSS `.selected.x-balls-left ~ .x-balls-left {display: none;}`

```js
$('.x-balls-left').click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('selected');  
})
```

```css
.selected.x-balls-left ~ .x-balls-left {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="balls-left">
            <h2>How Many Balls are Left on the Table?</h2>          
            <button type="button" id="balls-left-2" class="x-balls-left">2</button>
            <button type="button" id="balls-left-3" class="x-balls-left">3</button>
            <button type="button" id="balls-left-4" class="x-balls-left">4</button>
            <button type="button" id="balls-left-5" class="x-balls-left">5</button>
            <button type="button" id="balls-left-6" class="x-balls-left">6</button>
            <button type="button" id="balls-left-7" class="x-balls-left">7</button>
            <button type="button" id="balls-left-8" class="x-balls-left">8</button>
            <button type="button" id="balls-left-9" class="x-balls-left">9</button>
            <button type="button" id="balls-left-10" class="x-balls-left">10</button>
            <button type="button" id="balls-left-11" class="x-balls-left">11</button>
            <button type="button" id="balls-left-12" class="x-balls-left">12</button>
            <button type="button" id="balls-left-13" class="x-balls-left">13</button>
            <button type="button" id="balls-left-14" class="x-balls-left">14</button>
            <button type="button" id="balls-left-15" class="x-balls-left">15</button>
        </section>
```

Comment: This works, and seem particularly slick. It took me a little while to understand it, but now that I do I like it even more.  Many thanks to you, and to all the other who were so quick to offer up working approaches.

Comment: Just realized this needs more work. If on the next turn the player hasn't made any balls (this is a pool scoring app) he'd click on the highest numbered button, (same number still on table) but instead of doing nothing, it brings back the most recently hidden buttons.

Comment: @JohnBiddle I was using `toggleClass` for demo purpose only. If you need buttons to work one way you need to use `addClass` instead.

Comment: Thanks, Yuri, I realized that shortly after I commented to you.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps.

```
var exploded = id.split("-");
alert(exploded.pop());
```

Now, to use that concept on your HTML structure, you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".x-balls-left").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var exploded = this.id.split("-");
        alert(exploded.pop());
    });
});
```

And here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/57goqLk6/) you can play around with.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.balls-left', function() {
  var num = getNum(this);
  $('.balls-left').each(function() {
    var that = $(this); 
    var bnum = getNum(that);
    if (bnum > num) {
      that.show();
    } else {
      that.hide();
    }
  });
});

var getNum = function(elem) {
  if (elem) {  
    return $(elem).attr('id').replace('balls-left-', '');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="balls-left-1" class="balls-left">Ball 1</div>
<div id="balls-left-2" class="balls-left">Ball 2</div>
<div id="balls-left-3" class="balls-left">Ball 3</div>
<div id="balls-left-4" class="balls-left">Ball 4</div>
<div id="balls-left-5" class="balls-left">Ball 5</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#balls-left button:gt(num_balls-2)").hide;
```

This is an invalid CSS selector, and only *gets* the `hide` method, without calling it. You want something like:

```
$("#balls-left button:gt("+(num_balls-2)+")").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should put a class on each object so you can reference them all at once, and the simplest way to understand is to just put the ball number right in the tag as a custom attribute if you can:

```
<input type="button" id="balls-left-1" class="left-ball" num="1"/>
<input type="button" id="balls-left-2" class="left-ball" num="2"/>
etc...
```

Then you can write the javascript as follows:

```
$('.left-ball').click(function () {
    var BallNum = $(this).attr('num');

    $('.left-ball').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('num') > BallNum) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You should use `data-num` instead of just `num`.

Comment: Agreed, that would be a more precise use of a custom attribute.

Comment: Also, this can be made MUCH more efficient.  the whole each loop can be done with just one line with a better selector of course... but for the novice web developer, this will probably make the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx match like this. This might resolve your undefined num_balls error message.

```
$("#balls-left-14").click(function() {
    var ret = $(this).attr('id').match("[0-9]+");
    var  num_balls = ret[0];
    j_end_balls_on_table = 14;
    $("#balls-left button:gt(num_balls-2)").hide;
    ...
    other stuff
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it using your original HTML:

```
$('.x-balls-left').click(function () {
    var BallNum = $(this)[0].innerHTML;

    $('.x-balls-left').each(function () {
        if ($(this)[0].innerHTML > BallNum) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did it like this:

```
 $('button[id^=balls-left-]').click(function(){
     var num_balls = $(this).attr('id').match(/[\d]/);
     $('#balls-left button:gt(' + num_balls + ')').hide();
 });
```

Keep in mind that `:gt` select by index, it means that `$('#balls-left button:gt(2)')` will not select the button with id `balls-left-2` but the one with id `balls-left-4` (according to the html you posted).